# On table loaded from angular's ng-repeat, call a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to fire off a JavaScript function after a table has been fully filled from the ng-repeat directive?

Comment: What do you want to do after table is fully filled?

Comment: Call a function to see if the table's body has a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using the below directive

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

then in your controller, you can catch it with $on:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
      //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...
});
```

add below directives into  your table rebdering code

```
ng-repeat="item in items" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished"
```